# Error creating account with Firebase admin

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am trying to create an account for a user using Firebase functions and Firebase admin. When trying to create an account I get the following error:

```
Access Not Configured. Google Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project 252096998845 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://...
```

The thing is, the project number it gives me in the error message if different from my current project number. Somehow it has the wrong project? All my other functions runs fine with no issues on my current project.

I've visited the URL it gives me, but the project obviously doesn't exist

This project was migrated from the 'old' Firebase, if that matters at all.

**EDIT:**
The appropriate sign in method is already enabled.
I am using the NodeJS Admin SDK.
I've already tried to select my project in the Google Console and look for the Identity Toolkit API, but it is already enabled.

Full error:

`An internal error has occurred. Raw server response: "{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"accessNotConfigured","message":"Access Not Configured. Google Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project 252096998845 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/overview?project=252096998845 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.","extendedHelp":"https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/overview?project=252096998845"}],"code":403,"message":"Access Not Configured. Google Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project 252096998845 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/overview?project=252096998845 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."}}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was initialising my app with `admin.inializeApp(functions.config().firebase)`. Initialising the app with the

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://XYZ.firebaseio.com/',
  storageBucket: 'gs://project-XYZ.appspot.com/'
});
```

method fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

go to your firebase account and find this

`authentication -> sign-in method`

it will display many sign in method like facebook, phone, google etc ..
enable google sign-in method and try again.

Comment: Ofc, see above :)

Comment: go to google api and select you project and enable  Identity Toolkit API

Comment: Did that, API already enabled :/ But the issue seems to be that it has the wrong project

Comment: which library use for authentication ?

Comment: NodeJS SDK. Shouldn't matter though

Comment: or firebase configuration are wrong can you check it ?

Comment: What do you mean? I have selected the correct project in the console yes, but the project in the error message is wrong. Firebase Config is correct.

Comment: go to your Google Developers Console and open API & Auth / Credentials and click "Edit allowed referers" empty the input field.

Comment: Can you eleborate on those steps? I dont see that option anywhere?

Comment: okay again disable  `Identity Toolkit API ` and refresh page and after enable `Identity Toolkit API` and try